# $I=[a,b]$ and $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and for all $x$ in $I$ such property does hold

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity

Assume $I=[a,b]$ and $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous on $I$ and for all $x$ in $I$ exists  $y \in I$ such that $\left|f\left(y\right)\right|\le\frac{1}{2}\left|f\left(x\right)\right|$ prove that there exists a number $c$ in $I$ such that $f(c)=0$.

---

For $x_1 \in I$ exists $x_2 \in I$ such that $\left|f\left(x_2\right)\right|\le\frac{1}{2}\left|f\left(x_1\right)\right|$,inductively it's possible to find a sequence $(x_n) \in I$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$:$$\left|f\left(x_{n+1}\right)\right|\le\frac{1}{2}\left|f\left(x_n\right)\right|$$
And so
$$\left|f\left(x_{n+1}\right)\right|\le\frac{1}{2}\left|f\left(x_{n}\right)\right|\le\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}\left|f\left(x_{n-1}\right)\right|\le...\le\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}\left|f\left(x_{2}\right)\right|\le\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}\left|f\left(x_{1}\right)\right|$$

From here we see that the sequence $\left\{f\left(x_{n}\right)\right\}_n$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb R$ and by Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem there exists a subsequence $\left\{f\left(x_{n_k}\right)\right\}_k$ of $\left\{f\left(x_{n}\right)\right\}_n$ which converges to $f(c)$,on the other hand $$f(c)=\lim f(x_{n_k})=0 $$

I have two problems here,first how do we really "inductively" can find a sequence $(x_n) \in I$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$:$\left|f\left(x_{n+1}\right)\right|\le\frac{1}{2}\left|f\left(x_n\right)\right|$

Besides I have not used the fact that $f$ is continuous ,if I could show that $(x_n)$ is bounded then I could use  Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem to conclude that there exists a subsequence $\left(x_{n_k}\right)$  which converges to $c$,and continuity of $f$ implies that $f(c)=\lim f(x_{n_k})=0 $,but I cannot show that $(x_n)$ is bounded.

Comment: You certainly have used the fact that $\;f\;$ is continuous: how do you know that when you take the limit of $\;f(x_{n_k})\;$ , you end up with $\;f(c)\;$ (i.e., how do you know you end up with some element in the image of $\;f\;$ ) and not mere ly with a limit $\;L\;$ that who knows where it is?

Comment: And $\;\{x_n\}\;$ is bounded simply because the main characteristic of $\;f\;$ happens within $\;[a,b]\;$ , which is a bounded interval...

Comment: That is how **you define inductively** the sequence $\;\{x_n\}\;$ , of course. Just as you began with $\;x_1, x_2, ...\;$ etc., you continue inductively in that way, meaning: once we've defined up to $\;x_n\;$ , then by the first two lines in your post there exists $\;x_{n+1}\in I\;$ s.t. $\;|f(x_n)|\le\frac12|f(x_{n+1})\;$ , and then you continue on as you wrote.

Comment: Note that `\left|f\left(y\right)\right|\le\frac{1}{2}\left|f\left(x\right)\right|` can be shortened to `|f(y)|\le\frac 12|f(x)|`. The `\left` and `\right` are only needed when the standard height isn't right. And curly brackets on fractions are only needed when the numerator or denominator have more than one thing in them. Same goes for all your other expressions. Makes me wonder if they were automatically generated in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m=\inf \{|f(x)|: a \leq x \leq b\}$. There exists $c$ such that $|f(c)|=m$. There exist $y$ such that $|f(y)| \leq \frac 1 2 |f(c)| =\frac  m 2$. This is a contradicton unless $m=0$. Hence $f(c)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

> how do we really "inductively" can find a sequence

This is a procedure that's used quite frequently, but the full details are rarely spelled out. What you're doing is showing the following claim:

**Claim**: There exists a sequence $\{x_k\}$ in $[0,1]$ such that
$$ |f(x_{k+1})| \leq \frac12 |f(x_k)| $$
for all $k.$

*Proof*: We will prove by induction that for all $n,$ there exists $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ satisfying the above inequality for all $1 \leq k \leq n-1.$

For $n=1$ we can take $\{x_1\}$ with any $x_1 \in [0,1].$ By inductive hypothesis there exists $\{x_1,\dots,x_{n}\}$ exists satisfying the above for all $1 \leq k \leq n-1.$ By assumption on $f$ we know there exists some $x_{n+1}$ such that $|f(x_{n+1})|\leq \frac12 |f(x_n)|.$ Then the collection $\{x_1,\dots,x_{n+1}\}$ verifies the $(n+1)$ case.